# How to display a json response in a html table

Tags: javascript, api, html-table, response

I know the problem is the `data.map`.
Maybe its because map is made for arrays and i have an array of objects and not a array?

API-Response:

```
[
  {
    "id": 16,
    "nachname": "Köpper",
    "vorname": "Chris",
    "projectList": []
  },
  {
    "id": 13,
    "nachname": "Kämpfer",
    "vorname": "Gerrit",
    "projectList": [
      {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "FB.de"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "DFBnet"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "nachname": "Voges",
    "vorname": "Arved",
    "projectList": [
      {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "FB.de"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "DFBnet"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

HTML-Table:

```
<table class="table" id="output1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                <th scope="col">Vorname</th>
                <th scope="col">Nachname</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>

    </table>
```

js:

```
function getPerson(){
fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        var tableContent = document.querySelector('#output1 > tbody');
        data.map(function(instance) {
            const row = document.createElement('tr');
            tableContent.appendChild(row);
            instance.map(function(info) {
                const cell = document.createElement('td');
                cell.innerText = info;
                row.appendChild(cell);
            });
        });
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a jsfiddle to help you out. Map is for array, so you're missing one step (iterate object attributes, one for cell).

```js
let content = [{
    "id": 16,
    "nachname": "Köpper",
    "vorname": "Chris",
    "projectList": []
  },
  {
    "id": 13,
    "nachname": "Kämpfer",
    "vorname": "Gerrit",
    "projectList": [{
        "id": 9,
        "name": "FB.de"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "DFBnet"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "nachname": "Voges",
    "vorname": "Arved",
    "projectList": [{
        "id": 9,
        "name": "FB.de"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "DFBnet"
      }
    ]
  }
]


function getPerson() {
  Promise.resolve(content)
    //fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      var tableContent = document.querySelector('#output1 > tbody');
      data.map(function(instance) {
        const row = document.createElement('tr');

        for (let c of ['id', 'nachname', 'vorname']) {
          let cell = document.createElement('td');
          if (instance.hasOwnProperty(c)) {
              cell.innerText = instance[c]
          }

          row.appendChild(cell)
        }

        tableContent.appendChild(row)
      });
    })
}

getPerson()
```

```html
<table class="table" id="output1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Vorname</th>
      <th scope="col">Nachname</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If `data` is an array of objects, then `instance` is one single object within that array. You can't `map` over an object directly. If you are trying to create a table cell for each key/value pair, I would suggest looking at `Object.values()` or `Object.entries` to create the array that you can then iterate (`map`) over.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Something like:

```
Object.values(instance).map(function(info) {
  const cell = document.createElement('td');
  cell.innerText = info.toString();
  row.appendChild(cell);
});
```

Although you would need to decide how you want to represent `projectList` in the table as well, perhaps by iterating again and creating an inner table or concatenating the values together to a string.

If I'm missing something important about your use case, feel free to comment and I'll amend my answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, the problem is not with `data.map`, because the map function works on any kind of array whether it is plain array or array of objects.The problem in your code is regarding the `instance.map` , since the individual element of data array is an object. Therefore either we can use `for...in` statement as below

```
function getPerson() {
      fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        var tableContent = document.querySelector('#output1 > tbody');
        data.map(function (instance) {
          const row = document.createElement('tr');
          tableContent.appendChild(row);
          for (key in instance) {
            if (key !== 'projectList') {
              const cell = document.createElement('td');
              cell.innerText = instance[key];
              row.appendChild(cell);
            }
          }
        });
      })
    }
```